# How to handle model binding exceptions in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

Create a simple ASP.NET Core MVC web application from the template. Create a class called `Human`:

```
public class Human
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

Now create a `HumanController` to post a human instance:

```
[HttpPost]
public Human Post([FromBody] Human human)
{
    return human;
}
```

Using Fiddler or PostSharp (or any other client) post these JSON objects to this service:

```
{
    "Name": "someone"
}
```

and

```
{
    "Name": "someone",
    "Age": "invalid age"
}
```

and

```
{
    "Name": "someone",
    "Birthday": null
}
```

Since `Birthday` can't be null and `"invalid age"` can't be parsed as valid model properties, what we get in our service parameter is null. That has proved to be hard to debug.

Is there a way that we can configure ASP.NET Core MVC to either only partially bind models as much as it can, or to somehow let us hook into its default behavior so that we can catch the exception and notify client about wrong data it has sent?

Comment: Have you considered checking the model state to see if the binding errors are listed there?

Comment: We want to somehow do it outside each action. Something like Middleware or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add Proper Attributes to your Model you can Handel it and return Proper Error Message to Clients. 
For example you can put some Requirments on `Name` like :

```
    public class Human
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

In this way you can Check your model and if it is not valid return `BadRequest` like :

```
 public IActionResult Index(Human model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest("message");
        //to do
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Not at all the answer I want. First of all, I don't want to declarative validation, cause it's not powerful and in complex validations it fails and for the sake of consistency I'm using imperative validation all over the places. Second, I don't want to bother to create specific messages all over the places with boilerplate code. As I've said in question, I'm looking for a general way to configure ASP.NET Core MVC.

Comment: This answer combined with validatemodelattribute is the way to go.

Comment: Model binding exception will occur before executing controller action so answer is not valid at least for .net core 3.1.